# Как принимать/передавать файлы с одного сервера на другой?

Tags: php, файлы, хранение-данных, передача-данных

Ситуация примерно такая: у меня есть сайт, на который пользователи могут загружать свои фоточки/видео/музыку/прочую ерунду. Хранить это всё на одном сервере для меня не комильфо. Подскажите способ который позволит быстро, без особой нагрузки на два сервера, передавать файлы.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выделить отдельный поддомен(поддомены по количеству серверов). Например static1.domain.com, static2.domain.com.

Делать upload файлов на эти адреса и выводить в html полные пути до файлов `<img src="http://static1.domain.com/avatar/vasya.jpg"/>`

Этот подход полностью снимает нагрузку с "основного" сервера, однако, требует некоторых архитектурных решений. Например, загружать файлы лучше через ajax(тут вы столкнетесь с [cors](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)), если используется несколько серверов статики, нужно каким-то образом сохранять/разрешать с какого сервера брать файл.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то:
Загружать файлы сразу же на второй сервер через ftp или ssh, а в базе данных писать путь к файлу на второй сервер.
Использовать rsync по крону и синхронизировать файлы, либо через scp после чего вычищать директорию на первом сервере. На первом сервере хранить ссылки на файлы расположенные на втором сервере.

Answer (score 0):

1. FTP
2. Сразу загружать на целевой сервер, но для этого нужно иметь возможность прописать заголовки Origin
3. Как написали выше, S3
4. Как написали выше - распределенная ФС. Стоит посмотреть что такое NFS

У меня всё реализовано на FTP, так как использую VPS с 10Гб SSD и 30 Гб обычного хостинга...

Answer (score -2):

Храните в S3, например. Ну, или распределённая ФС какая-нибудь.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше мнение?

Comment: Я рассматривал S3. Это довольно дорого, особенно когда будет большой трафик. В один день я обнаружу, что даже продав почку, я не расплачусь с Amazon.